# running 2 SQL select statements

Tags: php, union-all

I am trying to run 2 SQL Select queries to retrieve data from 2 different tables and then echo the fields from both tables. The code I am trying doesn't seem to work, any help would be appreciated.

```
$ModelID = $_GET['model_id'];

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT RegNumber, Colour FROM Car WHERE ModelID = '$ModelID'

UNION ALL

SELECT CarModel, CarMake, CostPerDay FROM Model WHERE ModelID = '$ModelID'");   

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())    
{     
    echo $row["CarModel"];
    echo $row["CarMake"];
    echo $row["CostPerDay"];    
    echo $row["RegNumber"];        
    echo " - " .$row["Colour"];         
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an union and not a join on modelId ?

Comment: I tried googling the solution and got recommended union

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change request :

```
SELECT c.RegNumber, c.Colour , m.CarModel, m.CarMake, m.CostPerDay FROM Car c INNER JOIN Model m ON m.ModelID=c.ModelID WHERE c.ModelID = '$ModelID'
```

Answer (score 1):

try with LEFT JOIN

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 
   "SELECT c.RegNumber, c.Colour, m.CarModel, m.CarMake, m.CostPerDay 
   FROM Car AS c
   LEFT JOIN Model as m ON c.ModelID = m.ModelID 
   WHERE c.ModelID = '".$ModelID."'"
);
```